# Multisig wallet is not converted. Why aggregated transaction does not return error?

Tags: nem

I haven't converted account to multisig and I try to make aggregated transaction from it. No error occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With catapult you will not get any blockchain related errors. If you anounce a transaction it will always give you a ok back. You need to listen to an account to see if what you announce is correct and you have enough funds etc

Answer (score 0):

An aggregate transaction can be made from a normal account as well as a multisig one.

For a normal account think of it simply as a combination of multiple transactions into one transaction and it can be:

1- Aggregate complete if you have all the private keys necessary to sign the transactions you included in your aggregate transaction

2- bounded if you don't have all the initiators private keys and you need to announce it first

However for a multisig account all transactions must be wrapped in an aggregate and again it depends if you have all cosignatories private keys or not to announce it as complete or bounded